# How to set the form title

Tags: nsis

The form displays with "Name Setup" as the form caption. I understand how to set the titles of the individual installer pages (Welcome, Finish etc), but how do you set the form caption of the installer interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually setting [`Name`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.1.30) is enough for the title and all pages.

To customize the default title use [`Caption`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.1.7) or to customize the subtitle on a per page basis use `SubCaption`, or `Caption` inside a `PageEx` block (If you are using the Modern UI, it has defines for most of these)

Answer (score 1):

For pages based on nsDialogs use macro **MUI_HEADER_TEXT**

Example:

```
Function nsDialogsPage
  !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "${LICENSE_TITLE}" "${LICENSE_SUBTITLE}"
  nsDialogs::Create /NOUNLOAD 1018
  ...
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```